# Rename Table Without Changing Index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with many millions of rows of data.  Shock, horror - the script that loaded the data (taking a long time to run) has confused two columns.  The data for 1st column is in the second column and vice versa.

It seems the easiest way to amend this is to rename the columns (I am not concerned about the order of the columns).  However, using sp_rename is too clever and updates the index which already refers to the correct column.

Does anyone know a fast way to achieve this swap?

The scripts below demonstrate the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    col1 INT NOT NULL,
    col2 INT NOT NULL,
    col3 INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex ON MyTable(col1, col3) 
GO
```

So far so good.  Now imagine the data load has completed and we realise that the data is in the incorrect columns.  So I run the following scripts:

```
sp_rename 'MyTable.col1', 'col1ToCol2', 'COLUMN'
GO
sp_rename 'MyTable.col2', 'col1', 'COLUMN'
GO
sp_rename 'MyTable.col1ToCol2', 'col2', 'COLUMN'
GO
```

The columns are 'swapped' as expected.  However, on examining index MyIndex, the columns in it are now col2 and col3, not col1 and col3 as I want and need.

I would expect that dropping and re-creating the index would be very expensive.

In summary, how can I 'swap' the data in two columns where I am dealing with a very large indexed table?  Specifically, using SQL Server 2008R2

Thanks.

Comment: You have to recreate the index. You can't rename a column, while renaming another to the other's old name and expect SQL Server to "automagically" know what the order of every record in the new column is.

Comment: @Larnu, I wasn't expecting magic.  I merely expected a broken index pointing at a non-existant column, until the correct column names existed.  However, you have made me think (well done!) and I realise that I am being stupid.  the index is based on  the contents of the columns, so I could not possibly expect it to be correct following the swap.

Comment: So you indexed the wrong data. I think you'll have to re create the index.

Comment: The index is correct it just points to a column formerly known as Prince.  Why not use a clustered index?